# How to add sectionHeader like tableview header in IGListKit

Tags: ios, swift

IGListKit Library Link: https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit

Im making different section cell using IGListKit. I successfuly done this task but i cant be able to add headers for different sections using iglistKit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of IGListKit 2.1, consider class and protocol names prefixed by `IG`. This prefix was removed starting at 3.0.

In your section controller class, besides inheriting from `IGListSectionController` (and implementing `IGListSectionType`, on IGListKit 2.x), you'll also need to implement `IGListSupplementaryViewSource` and set to your section controller `self.supplementaryViewSource = self`.

You may want to check in the IGListKit official examples the class [`FeedItemSectionController`](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/blob/master/Examples/Examples-iOS/IGListKitExamples/SectionControllers/FeedItemSectionController.swift).

Of course, you could also implement this protocol in a separate entity, but actually [IGListKit was not designed for that](https://github.com/Instagram/IGListKit/pull/715). My team was able to do it by adding some more complexity in the way the section controller injects some of its data into this separate `IGListSupplementaryViewSource` implementer.

Comment: can you send me example project repo on github

Comment: The name FeedSectionController in my answer is a link to one of the official IGListKit examples. Just clone the IGListKit repo and the Examples directory will come altogether.